# npm publish throws "EPERM: operation not permitted" error

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm simply just trying to publish to artifactory and it throws the following error:

```
00:02:28.815 + npm publish
00:02:32.492 npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\temp\npm-7392-703923f8\tmp\fromDir-9a6c7c01\package.tgz
00:02:32.492 npm ERR! code EPERM
00:02:32.493 npm ERR! errno -4048
00:02:32.493 npm ERR! syscall unlink
00:02:32.496 npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\WINDOWS\temp\npm-7392-703923f8\tmp\fromDir-9a6c7c01\package.tgz'
00:02:32.497 npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\WINDOWS\temp\npm-7392-703923f8\tmp\fromDir-9a6c7c01\package.tgz'
00:02:32.497 npm ERR!   cause: 
00:02:32.497 npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\WINDOWS\temp\npm-7392-703923f8\tmp\fromDir-9a6c7c01\package.tgz'
00:02:32.498 npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
00:02:32.498 npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
00:02:32.498 npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
00:02:32.498 npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\temp\\npm-7392-703923f8\\tmp\\fromDir-9a6c7c01\\package.tgz' },
00:02:32.498 npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
00:02:32.499 npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\WINDOWS\\temp\\npm-7392-703923f8\\tmp\\fromDir-9a6c7c01\\package.tgz\'',
00:02:32.499 npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
00:02:32.499 npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
00:02:32.499 npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
00:02:32.499 npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\temp\\npm-7392-703923f8\\tmp\\fromDir-9a6c7c01\\package.tgz' }
00:02:32.500 npm ERR! 
00:02:32.500 npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I've tried every solution that I could find online and nothing has worked.

Comment: This is unrelated to Artifactory. You are getting stuck on NPM itself. the publishing has not yet reached Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

The process doesn't have enough rights. You are actually accessing `C:\WINDOWS` which requires admin privileges.

So, Open cmd or powershell as `admin` and run the script.

Example: `right-click -> Run as Admin`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I ran the artifactory standalone the first time while the port '8081' was taken by another app. The standalone files got corrupted by this scenario.

After unzipping a fresh version of the artifactory standalone, the `npm publish` worked fine.

You can also get this error if your not already logged in, before publishing, you should do an `npm login`.